# How can I program a progressive static counter on the same line in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, counter

I need to count the cases that a script is processing.

I don't want it to be line by line, like this:

line1 >>> 1

line2 >>> 2

line3 >>> 3

And also not like this:

line 1 >>> 1  2  3

I need it to be static and stay fixed so that the unit, ten and hundred are displayed:

line 1 >>> 001

I know it won't print the two zeros on the left, but it's just to explain what I need.

Thank you very much to anyone who can help me.

Comment: what I want is for the counter to be fixed on the same line and in the initial position, Just as the second hand of a digital watch would look.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy, you just need to play around whit the `'\n'` and `'\r'` chars...

```
print("line >>> {:3d}".format(the_number_you_want_print), end='\r')
```

A sample could be like this:

```
import time  
for i in range(100):
    time.sleep(1)
    print("line >>> {:3d}".format(i), end='\r')
```

The \n character prints out a newline, the \r character instead go just to the beginning of current line, without print a new one.
The `end` parameter of the `print` function changes the default `'\n'` with whatever you need

Comment: Thanks for the CyberMat97 script, however this only does what I indicate in the second case:
line1 >>> 1 line1 >>> 2 line1 >>> 3
What I want is for the number to stay in the same position as the previous one:
line1 >>> 1 (after 10 counts)
line1 >>> 10 (after 100 counts)
line1 >>> 100
It is difficult to explain it in writing.

Comment: I ensure you it works as your wish on Linux, on windows the output could be different, but on my computer when I launch the program in the terminal it does exactly what you are asking: it prints out always the 'i' variable in the same position.
Maybe I didn't get correctly the question...

Comment: Thanks but in windows unfortunately it doesn't run as you say it happens in linux. I understand that using Python3 there should be no difference from what is shown on the screen. If I make a script in Python and it works well in windows but not in linux then what is wrong is not the operating systems but python, which I don't think is true.